# How to use filterXML function to return numbers only?

Tags: excel, formula, filterxml

Cell A1 have the following values:

```
ABC@10
Gg hh ii@20
BB@30
```

All numeric values must be after @.

I would like to add all numeric values, i.e. 10 + 20 + 30 = 60.

I asked chatGBT and it said it can use

```
=SUMPRODUCT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"@","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[number(.)=.]"))
```

However, the formula return the array of last number 30 only, not 10 and 20.

Is anyone know how to modify the formula, so the array formula can become {10,20,30}.

Any help or idea are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: change `SUBSTITUTE(A1,"@","</s><s>")` to `SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</s><s>"),"@","</s><s>")` to also put the breaks at the line breaks.

Comment: with office 365: `=SUM(--TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"@",CHAR(10)),,-1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `SUBSTITUTE(A1,"@","</s><s>")` to `SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</s><s>"),"@","</s><s>")`.

With Office 365:

```
=SUM(--TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"@",CHAR(10)),,-1))
```

Answers courtesy of [Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner).